# What is causing the error `make: Nothing to be done for 'x.o'.` for some x?

Tags: makefile, ats

I added a new target (`main.o`) to an existing project:

```
DATS_FILES = main.dats
HFILES  = config.h es.h gc.h input.h prim.h print.h sigmsgs.h \
          stdenv.h syntax.h term.h var.h
CFILES  = access.c closure.c conv.c dict.c eval.c except.c fd.c gc.c glob.c \
          glom.c input.c heredoc.c list.c c_main.c match.c open.c opt.c \
          prim-ctl.c prim-etc.c prim-io.c prim-sys.c prim.c print.c proc.c \
          sigmsgs.c signal.c split.c status.c str.c syntax.c term.c token.c \
          tree.c util.c var.c vec.c version.c y.tab.c dump.c

src     :
        @echo ${OTHER} ${CFILES} ${HFILES} ${DATS_FILES}


list.o : list.c es.h config.h stdenv.h gc.h 
main.o : main.dats
match.o : match.c es.h config.h stdenv.h
```

As can be seen above, I have tried to give the new source `.dats` file the same status as the `.c` files in the project, which have no problems building.

If I try to build the target directly I get:

```
make main.o
make: Nothing to be done for 'main.o'.
```

This happens even if I run `touch main.dats`. If I compile `main.dats` manually after `make` fails, then run `make` again, the project finishes building and the output executable runs without issue. Here is the complete [Makefile.in](https://github.com/bbarker/fsh/blob/868bc8f9ec32ae2e5ed8f7168cbca56380c7caf2/Makefile.in).

Comment: I might be wrong since I'm no expert of makefiles, but I do not see any rule explaining how to generate `main.o` from `main.dats`. It is possible that because of the lack of rule `main.o` is considered as a phony target, such as `src`?

Comment: (note that AFAIK make already has an implicit rule for `*.o` files when they are dependent on `*.c` or `*.cpp` files which uses environment variables `CC` and `CXX`)

Comment: see https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Catalogue-of-Rules.html#Catalogue-of-Rules

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to add a rule to specify to `make` how to re-create `main.o` starting from `main.dats`. For C files make knows what to do, but for `.dats` files it doesn't. In particular, you have to change:

```
main.o : main.dats
```

with

```
main.o : main.dats
        (your-compiler) (your-compiler-options) -o main.o main.dats
```

(assuming that is the syntax in your compiler for specifying input and output files)

IMPORTANT: indentation of the second (and the following) lines have to be done with tabs and not spaces, because that's how make works.

In your case (assuming `.dats` is the extension for dynamic ATS language) I think it should be

```
main.o : main.dats
        patscc -c -o main.o main.dats
```

edit: if you have more than one `.dats` file to compile you can add a generic rule that teach `make` to invoke the right compiler for them (thanks to Toby for the syntax)

```
%.o : %.dats
        patscc -c -o $@ $<
```

I am not sure what is the priority for application when both a `main.c` and `main.dats` are present.

Comment: Or better, just write a pattern rule for `%.o: %.dats` (I'm assuming GNU Make here).  Something like `patscc -c -o $@ $<` should do it.

Comment: @TobySpeight solution in fact works exactly as stated, but @pqnet's solution should also work. I thought I was good sense I was just using `patscc` to also compile *.c files (by setting `CC=patscc` as in that case it will just wrap e.g. gcc), but @pqnet is correct about the special handling of C files in Make.

Comment: @TobySpeight yeh that's the rule that for C/C++ is implicit